# Where would be the best location to mount a distributed filesystem?

Tags: cifs, distributed-filesystem

We are looking at mounting a distributed file system on our RHEL machines and we think that the best location to mount the share is at /var/dfs. Where would the best location be to mount this share?

Comment: What's the filesystem used for? Or is it a general purpose share?

Comment: It is a general purpose share.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it wherever you want, and the "best" location will be subjective.

However, you can take some guidance from [the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), which recommends using `/media` for removable media and `/mnt` for temporarily-mounted filesystems.

In my experience, I've also seen `/mnt` used for any non-essential mounts (that is, things that don't have the home directory or `/boot` on them).

Comment: The fact that /mnt is used for temporarily-mounted filesystems is what initially led me to consider /var/dfs and this will not be a temp mount.

Comment: So it is not a temp mount, but what will it be used for? The location is subjective and depends on what the filesystem will be used for. I have seen and used

 - /home
 - /usr/local
 - /opt/data
 - /hadoop and others

Comment: Another FHS-based answer might be to use a subdirectory of [srv](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s17.html).